# Is it possible to charge iCloud Storage plan to a different payment method than other App Store purchases?

Tags: icloud

Since I use iCloud Storage partially for business, I'd like to put the regular charge onto a different credit card.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the other card to your Apple ID and move it to the top of the list.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201266

> Apple will attempt to charge payment methods in order from top to bottom.